# Cant send empty checkbox value in phpmailer

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

I'm working in a e-mail form using phpmailer, there is a problem every-time checkboxes are kept empty, so I figure out the problem is in the expression bellow:

```
$f_select = '';
foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
    $f_select .= $value."\r\n";
}
```

It is returning the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/alive-web-tech/www/nagoyashobotenken/contact/complete.php on
>   line 23

How can I fix this problem? I guess I need to create a condition telling that when the checkbox value is empty something must happen to prevent the error.

Comment: Can't you put an if condition before the foreach saying something like `if(!empty($_POST['select']))` then you do the foreach

Comment: Following your advice, I just tried something like this, but it did not work: if(!empty($_POST['select'])) {
 $f_select = 'ok';
} else {
 $f_select = '';
 foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
  $f_select .= $value."\r\n";
 }
}

Comment: Because that's not how you put an if condition :) I was going to write how in an answer but someone else already did, too bad lol I wanted the points :P

Comment: Sorry for my bad grammar, I am used to javascript, but php still hard for me.

Comment: you simply check the this condition $chk = isset( $_POST['Your-chk-name'] ) ? $_POST[Your-chk-name] : ' ' ;  after that check if( ! empty( $chk ) ){ Your Code; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. If you really need the values of the checkboxes even if they were not checked then you must update your form to include an hidden input with value 0 for each checkbox you have:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="select[firstCheckbox]" value="0" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="select[firstCheckbox]" />
   ```
2. If you don't care about the empty values of the checkbox then you can simply verify if the posted data is empty before entering the loop:

   ```
   $f_select = '';
   if (!empty($_POST['select'])) {
       foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
           $f_select .= $value."\r\n";
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your `$_POST['select']` is empty before call `foreach()` over it.

You can try something like:

```
$f_select = '';
 if (!empty($_POST['select'])) {
   foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
     $f_select .= $value."\r\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `$_POST['select]` before you loop through its contents.

```
$f_select = '';

if (!empty($_POST['select'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
        $f_select .= $value."\r\n";
    }
}
```